# Is there a git workflow to describe this scenario?

Tags: git, git-workflow

Currently working from two branches : `develop`

Feature branches are created from develop and when the changes is complete the feature branch is then merged back to develop.

Currently, we are working on a significant update named `u1` that will not be complete for 3 months. In the meantime, we will need to provide other functionality and hotfixes to the current release that is unrelated to u1.

To accomplish this change, I suggest the following :

Create a new branch from develop that will include only the features for `u1`. All u1 related features will be added to the `u1` branch. Continue to create hotfixes etc, feature branches from develop and merge the hotfixes to develop. At some point when `u1` is feature complete merge the `u1` branch to `develop` (which contains the hotfixes previously described). Is there a name for this git strategy, are there alternative ways of managing this git workflow ?

Comment: You've not described when `develop` is actually merged into `master`. So according to your description that's unneded.

Comment: @JoachimSauer true, I've removed that reference, thanks.

Comment: It seems like ordinary git flow to me. This happens _any_ time a feature branch takes time. Hard to see what the actual question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general practice that I have encountered consists of the following rules:

- there is a `master` branch, which is equivalent to the code in production
- there is a `develop` branch, which is used to stage and test feature branches
- a feature branch is created from `master`
- when a feature branch is ready for testing, merge it to `develop`
- if the feature branch's test was unsuccessful, then return to it
- if the feature branch's test was successful, then before you deploy, merge it to `master`
- just before deployment, you do a smoke test on `master`, that is, you test everything that realistically could go wrong as well as features of critical importance
- if the smoke test failed, determine what causes the problem and clean `master` and merge only the features that did not cause trouble
- if the smoke test succeeded, deploy
- hotfix branches are branched out from `master` and merged into `master` once they are completed
- if there is an epic feature branch, like the one that you have described, then organize it into divisible sub-tasks
- each subtask is a task branch branched out from the epic feature branch
- once a subtask is completed, merge it into your epic feature branch
- smoke test the epic feature branch before you merge it into `develop` and then smoke test `develop`
- never merge `develop` into `master`, since `develop` may contain untested features
- whenever a deploy occurred, merge `master` into `develop` as well as your epic feature branches